# Limit with Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }a_n$ be convergent, prove that$$\lim_{s\rightarrow 0+}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }a_nn^{-s}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }a_n.$$

If $a_n\geq 0$, it is OK by spliting the series into two parts $n\leq N$, $n>N$.

However, if $a_n\geq 0$ is not true, how can we show it?

Comment: You can utilize [*Abel's test*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_test#Abel.27s_uniform_convergence_test) to guarantee that the function $s \mapsto \sum_n a_n n^{-s}$ is continuous for $s \geq 0$. If you want to open up the argument behind this theorem, simply apply the summation by parts to convert the sum to a more tamed one.

Comment: @SangchulLee Let me try it. Thank you.